# .net core 6- JWT authentication with keycloak realm url

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, keycloak

I want to implement the jwt authentication with the keycloak URL in .net 6. I have a URL where get the certificate and other things. So anyone can help me with how I can implement that thing?

How we can use realm params in that validation?

Thanks

Comment: What's the setup? Will it be a web application with a user interface that would redirect the user to Keycloak for login? Or is it a backend REST service that just wants to validate the JWT of a REST request?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. There is one jwt option for pass the openId certificate URL. The option is MetadataAddress. We can add this option in our jwt configuration and it will call get the keys from URL and validate.

```
"Jwt" : {
   "MetaAddress": "{your keyclock url}/auth/realms/{projectname}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
   "Issuer": "{your keyclock url}/auth/realms/{projectname}"
}
```

You have to use this MetaAddress.AddJwtBearer's option of "MetaDataAddress". Also, use "Issuer" in the  "TokenValidationParameters"'s options.